# Play 2.4 macwire example with extended controllers doesn't seem like it can be mocked

Tags: scala, routes, mockito, playframework-2.4, macwire

I took the existing macwire example and extended the controller like so
CoffeeController.scala

```
package com.softwaremill.play24.controllers

import com.softwaremill.play24.dao.CoffeeDao
import play.api.i18n.Lang
import play.api.libs.json.Json
import play.api.mvc._

import scala.concurrent.{Future}
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext
import play.api.mvc.Results._

class CoffeeController(
  coffeeDao: CoffeeDao
)(implicit ec: SomeContextBuilder) extends AnotherController {

  def fetchAll() = DecoratedAction() { request =>
    coffeeDao.all.map { coffees =>
      Ok(Json.toJson(coffees))
    }
  }

  def priced(price: Double) = ResolvedDecoratedAction() { request =>
    coffeeDao.byPriceWithSuppliers(price).map { result =>
      Ok(Json.toJson(result.toMap))
    }
  }
}

trait ContextBuilder[U <: TraitLike] {
  def build(request: Request[AnyContent]): Future[Either[Result, RequestWithContext[U]]]
  def buildAuthenticated(request: Request[AnyContent]): Future[Either[Result, RequestWithResolvedContext[U]]]
}

trait TraitLike {
  def id: String
}

trait WithSessionId {
  self: RequestHeader =>
  lazy val sessionId = self.session.get("auth").getOrElse(java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString)
}

case class RequestWithContext[U <: TraitLike](request: Request[AnyContent], lang: Lang, anything: Option[U]) extends WrappedRequest(request) with WithSessionId
case class RequestWithResolvedContext[U <: TraitLike](request: Request[AnyContent], lang: Lang, anything: U, rememberMe: Boolean = false) extends WrappedRequest(request) with WithSessionId
case class Trait(val id: String) extends TraitLike

class AnotherController[U <: TraitLike](implicit ctxBuilder: ContextBuilder[U]) extends Controller  {
  def DecoratedAction(bodyParser: BodyParser[AnyContent] = parse.anyContent)(f: RequestWithContext[U] => Future[Result]) = Action.async {
    implicit request =>
      ctxBuilder.build(request) flatMap {
        case Left(r) =>
          Future.successful(r)
        case Right(requestContext) =>
          f(requestContext).map(_.addingToSession( ("auth" , requestContext.sessionId) ))
      }
  }

  def ResolvedDecoratedAction(bodyParser: BodyParser[AnyContent] = parse.anyContent)(f: RequestWithResolvedContext[U] => Future[Result]) = Action.async {
    implicit request =>
      ctxBuilder.buildAuthenticated(request) flatMap {
        case Left(r) =>
          Future.successful(r)
        case Right(requestContext) =>
          f(requestContext).map(_.addingToSession( ("auth", requestContext.sessionId) ))
      }
  }
}

class SomeContextBuilder extends ContextBuilder[TraitLike] {
  override def build(request: Request[AnyContent]): Future[Either[Result, RequestWithContext[TraitLike]]] = Future.successful(Right(RequestWithContext(request, Lang("en-us"),None)))

  override def buildAuthenticated(request: Request[AnyContent]): Future[Either[Result, RequestWithResolvedContext[TraitLike]]] = Future.successful(Right(RequestWithResolvedContext(request, Lang("en-us"),Trait("id"),false)))
}
```

ControllerModule.scala

```
package com.softwaremill.play24.modules

import com.softwaremill.macwire._
import com.softwaremill.play24.controllers.{SomeContextBuilder, SupplierController, CoffeeController}
import com.softwaremill.play24.dao.{CoffeeDao, SupplierDao}
import play.api.libs.ws.WSClient

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext

trait ControllerModule {

  // Dependencies
  implicit def ec: ExecutionContext
  implicit val ctxBuilder = wire[SomeContextBuilder]
  def wsClient: WSClient
  def supplierDao: SupplierDao
  def coffeeDao: CoffeeDao

  // Controllers
  lazy val supplierController = wire[SupplierController]
  lazy val coffeeController = wire[CoffeeController]
}
```

However when I run the tests I'm getting a stacktrace:

```
[error]   ! return priced by coffee, supplier
  [error]    No configuration setting found for key 'play.crypto.secret' (SimpleConfig.java:152)
[error] com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findKeyOrNull(SimpleConfig.java:152)
[error] com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findOrNull(SimpleConfig.java:170)
[error] com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findOrNull(SimpleConfig.java:176)
[error] com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findOrNull(SimpleConfig.java:176)
[error] com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findOrNull(SimpleConfig.java:193)
[error] com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findOrNull(SimpleConfig.java:198)
[error] com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getIsNull(SimpleConfig.java:208)
[error] play.api.PlayConfig.getOptional(Configuration.scala:951)
[error] play.api.PlayConfig.getOptionalDeprecated(Configuration.scala:996)
[error] play.api.libs.CryptoConfigParser.get$lzycompute(Crypto.scala:232)
[error] play.api.libs.CryptoConfigParser.get(Crypto.scala:203)
[error] play.api.libs.Crypto$$anonfun$crypto$1.apply(Crypto.scala:42)
[error] play.api.libs.Crypto$$anonfun$crypto$1.apply(Crypto.scala:40)
[error] play.api.libs.Crypto$.crypto(Crypto.scala:43)
[error] play.api.libs.Crypto$.sign(Crypto.scala:67)
[error] play.api.mvc.CookieBaker$class.encode(Http.scala:502)
[error] play.api.mvc.Session$.encode(Http.scala:651)
[error] play.api.mvc.CookieBaker$class.encodeAsCookie(Http.scala:554)
[error] play.api.mvc.Session$.encodeAsCookie(Http.scala:651)
[error] play.api.mvc.Result.withSession(Results.scala:170)
[error] play.api.mvc.Result.addingToSession(Results.scala:262)
[error] com.softwaremill.play24.controllers.AnotherController$$anonfun$ResolvedDecoratedAction$1$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(CoffeeController.scala:64)
[error] com.softwaremill.play24.controllers.AnotherController$$anonfun$ResolvedDecoratedAction$1$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(CoffeeController.scala:64)
```

I could try running(FakeApplication()){...} but then I get routes injector errors.  Currently the code uses routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator in the build.sbt, but I don't think it translates over into test phase.

I have put the code up on here
https://github.com/tashiscool/Play24MacwireMockingFailure

If you run activator test you should see the errors in the controllers tests.

Answer (score 1):

i ran into the exact same problem. i spent a little bit of time looking into it, it appears that via `FakeRequest#withSession`, you can end up calling some parts of the `Crypto` library within play that depend on config but have no way to pass in a `FakeApplication`.

...but i did find a simple workaround that might work for you as well. basically just wrapping `FakeRequest` with a mockito spy, and then stubbing the methods that try to call the internal `Crypto` API.

```
import org.mockito.Mockito.{doReturn, spy}
import play.api.mvc.{AnyContentAsEmpty, Session}
import play.api.test.FakeRequest

trait AuthSupport { 

  def fakeRequest(): FakeRequest[AnyContentAsEmpty.type] = {
    val request = spy(FakeRequest())
    doReturn(Session(Map("userId" -> "1"))).when(request).session
    request
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you didn't configured play secret in application.conf
Can you try and define it?

Look here for more [details](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ApplicationSecret)

Comment: I've tried that (even pushed it to github) but it didn't make any difference :(

Comment: Well the problem seems to be with the `play.crypto.secret` setting, not with macwire or mocking